# Submit a form without query string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, post, query-string

I'm on a page like `http://example.com?query=value` that has a form `<form id="formId" method="POST">`.

What's the best way to submit the form to `http://example.com` without the query string?

I'm currently trying:

```
$('#formId').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = window.location.href; 
    if (url.indexOf("?") != -1){
        $('#formId').attr('action', url.split("?")[0]);
    }
    $('#formId').submit();
});
```

but it doesn't seem to be working.

I prefer a javascript/jQuery solution as this pattern is common through the site

Comment: Umm what do you want?

Comment: Why don't you just set the `action` attribute in the HTML? In theory, it's a required attribute on `<form>` elements

Comment: @Phil because that would require knowledge of the page url during page initiation, which I don't have due to my templating strategy. Thus why I'm asking for a Javascript/jQuery solution, which would be easy to include on each page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of attempting to change the action on submit, how about just looking for forms without `action` attributes and setting them appropriately, for example

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('form:not([action])').attr('action', location.pathname);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else looking here, a quick and dirty solution is to set the form action attribute to "?". eg:

`<form id="formId" method="POST" action="?">`

This will post the request to the current url with the query string just being a single "?"

Though as this does not use javascript, it might not be the answer OP is after.